# Finding Log of a large BigInteger not working correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger, largenumber

I'm trying to find the logarithm of a very large BigInteger in C#.
I don't care what the base of the logarithm is.
When I try this:

```
BigInteger b = 1000; // the base
// myBigInt is a huge BigInt i want to find the Log of.

exponent = BigInteger.Log(myBigInt, 1000); //Find the Log
// Re-create the orignal BigInt now that I know base and exponent
BigInteger.Pow(b, Convert.ToInt32(exponent));
```

I get an overflow exception, because Int32 cannot hold the result of the Log.
Increasing the value of base doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post more of your code your missing some variables here.

Comment: @TheKingDave Ok, I explained the variables and made it simpler. I hope :)

Comment: Tried this and exponent in my case is a floating point value. To why are you converting it to an int ? I tried it with a VERY big myBigInt and it still doesn't crash.

Comment: The last b should be 1000.  If you are taking log based on 1000 then you need Pow based on 1000.

Comment: @TheKingDave Thanks for the answer. Yes, the exponent is a floating point value, but you have to convert it to int because the BigInteger.Pow method requires an int for the exponent value.
C# apparently doesn't let you raise a BigInteger to a floating point value power...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the same basis in the log and pow

```
BigInteger bigInt = 10000000000000000000;  // myBigInt is a huge BigInt i want to find the Log of.
double log;
log = BigInteger.Log(bigInt, 1000); //Find the Log
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(log.ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((Int32)log).ToString());
BigInteger bigIntRecreate;
// unless log is an integer value it will round down and will not recreate to proper value
bigIntRecreate = BigInteger.Pow(1000, (Int32)log);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bigInt.ToString("N0"));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bigIntRecreate.ToString("N0"));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((bigInt - bigIntRecreate).ToString("N0"));
```

Comment: thanks, it works now. It seems I can't upvote any of you unfortunately, I'm new here.

Comment: oops, didn't notice that. Done.